# jQuery.map() to Parse results from select2 ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jquery-select2

I have the following select2 ajax call. How do I use the jquery $.map() to parse the returned json results. From the users array i need to get the Text and Value results. From the pager array I need to get the TotalItemCount. What I have below doesnt seem to work i.e the search results don't seem to display in the select list. No console errors are shown either so I'm not sure what Im doing wrong.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetEmployees", "Employees")';
var pageSize = 20;

$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                term: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            params.page = params.page || 1;

            return {
                results:  $.map(data, function (users) {
                    return {
                        text: users.Text,
                        id: users.Value
                    }
                }),
               pagination: {
                    more: (params.page * pageSize) < data.pager.TotalItemCount
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    placeholder: "-- Select --",
    allowClear: true
});
```

The json returned is as follows:

```
 {
   "pager":{
      "PageCount":1,
      "TotalItemCount":1,
      "PageNumber":1,
      "PageSize":20,
      "HasPreviousPage":false,
      "HasNextPage":false,
      "IsFirstPage":true,
      "IsLastPage":true,
      "FirstItemOnPage":1,
      "LastItemOnPage":1
   },
   "users":[
      {
         "Disabled":false,
         "Group":null,
         "Selected":false,
         "Text":"Joe Blogs",
         "Value":"97306aa4-d423-4770-9b45-87a701146b10"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: The search results don't seem to be displayed in the select list to select from.

Comment: Which means the json is wrong or the $.map(data, function (users) is wrong?

Comment: Have not tried `select2`, can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Answer (score 4):

I was correct. I wasn't using the jQuery.map() correctly. It should be as follows:

```
 results:  $.map(data.users, function (users) {
                return {
                    text: users.Text,
                    id: users.Value
                }
            }),
```