# jQuery Select2 JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, json

My script won't load any data in the Select2. I made a test.php with JSON data (which will be provided external after everything works. (test.php is my internal test)).

**Output of test.php**

```
[{"suggestions": ["1200 Brussel","1200 Bruxelles","1200 Sint-Lambrechts-Woluwe","1200 Woluwe-Saint-Lambert"]}]
```

**jQuery script:**

```
$("#billing_postcode_gemeente").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    tags: [],
    ajax: {
        url: 'https://www.vooronshuis.nl/wp-content/plugins/sp-zc-checkout/test.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        quietMillis: 50,
        data: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        processResults: function(data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data.suggestions, function(obj) {
                    return {
                        id: obj.key, text: obj.value
                    }
                })
            };
        }
    }
});
```

I have been searching and checking all other solutions. It it not working for me. I'm stuck.

**Update: jQuery script so far**

```
    $("#billing_postcode_gemeente").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    placeholder: "Voer uw postcode in..",
    ajax: {
        url: 'https://www.vooronshuis.nl/wp-content/plugins/sp-zc-checkout/checkaddressbe.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        quietMillis: 50,
        data: function (data) {
            return {
            ajax_call: 'addressZipcodeCheck_BE',
            zipcode: '1200'
            };
        },
          processResults: function(data) {
              alert(data);
              correctedData = JSON.parse(data)[0]suggestions;
              alert(correctedData);
                return {
                  results: $.map(correctedData, function(obj) {
                    return {
                      id: obj.key,
                      text: obj.value
                    }
                  })
                };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any error in console? and what do you mean by internal test?

Comment: @SaadSuri With internal test, I mean I have setup a own test.php which echo the json code. Thats all. Now I see a error: 

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement - LINE: id: obj.key, text: obj.value

I hadn't this error earlier yet. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Updated: I added a return { } to it. Now no errors anymore. But still its not loading my JSON data if I enter '12'. It should show my data.

Comment: Is your json file on different server?

Comment: @SaadSuri: At this moment not. It is the same URL. Also the alert, is showing the following: [object Object]

Comment: remove the semicolon ';' from this line: id: obj.key, text: obj.value;

Comment: @KevinHR: Done. Still no data loading.

Comment: "processResults" is no a the function response ajax, change it and replace by "success" as the doc describe may be you can show us processResults?

Comment: @headmax This function does work within select. Please check other posts at Stackoverflow. It looks something goes wrong with the data set, and process it to show it in a dropdown for select2.

Comment: @nhatimme this function is used as a "prototype" isn't the real function as overwriting by hooking a function can you show me a link in the jquery doc where this function is related?

Comment: Just a warn about this because this no a plugin using $fn is jquery way this is the property way to overwriting function without troubles as you got or just use the normal way to manipulate your data.

Comment: Lets make it clear to everybody: What I want is to create a Select2. Within this Select2, if I type "12" (e.g.) it should display data with all 12... zipcodes and I want to be able to select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/saffrons/bgrr5a8n/) is a working fiddle for your example.
I have done if on a local JSON object but you can replicate the same results on your response or maybe change your response accordingly.

Your `data.suggestions` is nothing. Because `data` is a JSON array whose first element is a JSON object with key `suggestions` and value an array of suggestions.

Run this code in your JQuery enabled browser console and you will undestand.

```
var data = '[{"suggestions": ["1200 Brussel","1200 Bruxelles","1200 Sint-Lambrechts-Woluwe","1200 Woluwe-Saint-Lambert"]}]';
JSON.parse(data)[0];
JSON.parse(data)[0].suggestions;
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556750/jquery-map-to-parse-results-from-select2-ajax-call) answer to see how a proper response should look like.

Updated answer:
Sending additional data to back-end:

```
$('#billing_postcode_gemeente').DataTable(
{
 ......
                    "processing" : true,
                    "serverSide" : true,
                    "ajax" : {
                        url : url,
                        dataType : 'json',
                        cache : false,
                        type : 'GET',
                        data : function(d) {
                            // Retrieve dynamic parameters
                            var dt_params = $('#billing_postcode_gemeente').data(
                                    'dt_params');
                            // Add dynamic parameters to the data object sent to the server
                            if (dt_params) {
                                $.extend(d, dt_params);
                            }
                        }
                    },
});
```

Here `dt_params` is your additional parameter (the `zipcode`
 that you wish to send to the server to get an appropriate response). This dt_params gets added to the datatable parameters and can be accessed in your back-end to appropriate the response.

There must be a place where you are taking the `zipcode` entry. On the listener of that input box you can add the below code to destroy and recreate the datatable to reflect the changes. This code will add key-value (key being `zip_code`) pair to the `dt_params` key in your request JSON:

```
function filterDatatableByZipCode() {

        $('#billing_postcode_gemeente').data('dt_params', {
            ajax_call: 'addressZipcodeCheck_BE',
            zip_code : $('#some_imput_box').val()
        });
        $('#billing_postcode_gemeente').DataTable().destroy();
        initDatatable();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your perfect explanation. I now understand what happens. Last questions: I'm sending data to an URL like: `return { ajax_call: 'addressZipcodeCheck_BE', zipcode: '1500' }`. I want to make sure this dataresponse from the GET will be translated to correct Data. How should I do that?

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer for the community's benefit. 
If I understand correctly you wish to add `zipcode` to your datatable request object to get an appropriated response, if I am right I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks. What I want is searching in a Select2 box for lets say zipcode: 1200. It will do an AJAX call to a URL and gets a respond. This respond is as example: `[{"suggestions": ["1200 Brussel","1200 Bruxelles","1200 Sint-Lambrechts-Woluwe","1200 Woluwe-Saint-Lambert"]}]`. If the data is retreived, I want to parse it as you explained and show it in a dropdown at Select2 box. Do you fully understand me?

Comment: I updated my post with my current script. It does nothing with the var correctedData. Do you understand what I want now?

Comment: You are missing a (.) in `JSON.parse(data)[0]suggestions`. Change it to `JSON.parse(data)[0].suggestions`

Comment: Yeah I understood. There are 2 things you can do. 1) Load all the data i.e all the zip codes with the place-names. Select2 gives you searching by default. 2) If however the list is too long,you can call `filterDatatableByZipCode()` on the `keyup()` or `keydown()` event of `billing_postcode_gemeente` select bix. That will reinitialise the select2 with respect to the zipcode entered. To ensure smoothness of experience add a `.delay()` of 2-3 seconds so that for every keypress AJAX call is not fired instantly. Hope that answers everything.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
    ajax: {
         url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
         dataType: 'json',
         delay: 250,
         data: function (params) {
           return {
              q: params.term, // search term
              page: params.page
           };
        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data
           return data.items;
        },
        cache: true
   },
   minimumInputLength: 1,
   templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
   templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
});
```